# Android: how to use webservices with AsyncTasks

Tags: android, rest, mobile

This is my first post on this site, i have a problem with my app, i can't find the reason which my app stops. I am sending a request to Despegar to get a json of the countries but happens these. I would be very greatfull if you could help me.
 Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
final TextView txtResultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResultado);
String JSONRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new TareaConexion().execute("http://api.despegar.com/countries");

}
class TareaConexion extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        httpHandler httphandler = new httpHandler();
        JSONRequest = httphandler.Post(urls[0]);
        return JSONRequest;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate () {        
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
        txtResultado.setText(JSONRequest);
    }
 }
```

and the class httpHandler:

```
public class httpHandler {

public String Post (String PostURL)
{
    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(PostURL);

        HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
        HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();

        String Respuesta = EntityUtils.toString(ent); 

        return Respuesta;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "error";
    }
}
}
```

can anybody find the reason which do my app stops? what am i doing wrong?

i'm argentinian so excuse me if i make a mistake with the lenguage, ajja. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
    MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, HttpResponse> 
    {
        @Override
            protected HttpResponse doInBackground(String... param) 
            {
                String url = param[0];

                HttpResponse response = null;
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.connection-manager.timeout", 15000);
                try {

                    if (type == Constants.TYPE_POST)
                    {
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    }
                    else if (type == Constants.TYPE_DELETE)
                    {
                        HttpDelete httpdelete = new HttpDelete(url);
                        response = httpclient.execute(httpdelete);
                    }           
                    else
                    {
                        HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(url);
                        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    }       

                } catch (ClientProtocolException es) 
                {   
                    Log.e("x" , es.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    Log.e("aasx" , e.getMessage());
                }
                return response;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse response) 
            {
                if (response != null)
                {   
                      JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(Utilities.convertStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                   //Whatever you want to do        
                }
            }
        }
```